# Pythonic way to count the most frequent items with duplicates in Counter, separately by number of elements?

Tags: python, counter

I'm interested in a neat (+ optimal) way to solve the following problem, as I'm curious how to execute this in a Pythonic way. While doing a separate task, I attempted to make a `collections.Counter` dictionary with arbitrary elements:

```
d = Counter({('A','C'): 4, ('B','D','E'): 3, ..., ('A','G','V','X','Z'): 1, ('L','Z'): 1})
```

Here, each element is a tuple, consisting of 2 or more characters. My goal is to create a list with the most frequent items **with** duplicates *uniquely by the number of elements in a tuple*. For example, the solution may look like the following:

```
d_sample = Counter({('A', 'C'): 4, ('B', 'D', 'E'): 3, ('A' ,'D'): 3, ('C', 'D', 'E'): 3, 
                    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 2, ('A', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 1, 
                    ('B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 1, ('D', 'E'): 1})

result = [('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'E'), ('C', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
         ('A', 'C', 'D', 'E'), ('B', 'C', 'D', 'E')]
```

Here, `('A', 'C')` is selected, as it is the tuple with two elements with the highest count. `('B', 'D', 'E')` and `('C', 'D', 'E')` are both selected as they are the tuples with three elements with the highest count. Same goes for other elements in the `result` list.

The method I thought of was using a `for` loop to extract several lists from `d`, separated by number of elements: `for i in range(2, # maximum elements using another for loop)`. From there, I counted the item(s) with the highest frequency using another `for` loop and `max()`.

```
# pseudo-example:

maxval = 2

for x in d:
   if len(x[0]) > maxval:
       maxval = len(x[0])

counter_list = [[] * n for n in range(maxval-2)]

for x in d:
   counter_list[len(x[0])-2].append(x)

## selecting max per list
```

As elaborated, this doesn't seem Pythonic and optimal at all. Any insights to deliver the task more optimally would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input counter is already ordered by value. Can that be relied on, or it's a coincidence? The most optimal approach depends on this question..

Comment: @wim thanks for pointing that out. As this is a result from another previous task, the given Counter is already ordered but strictly by value, and within the same value the keys are unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *O(n)* and I don't think it will be possible to get asymptotically any better than that.

```
highest_count_for_length = {}
result = []
for tup, count in d.items():
    try:
        if highest_count_for_length[len(tup)] == count:
            result.append(tup)
    except KeyError:
        # we haven't seen this length yet
        highest_count_for_length[len(tup)] = count
        result.append(tup)
```

It does rely on the fact that the input is already ordered by value.

Comment: Does it have to be ordered in an ascending order, as opposed to the descending order as it is in the problem? I've run it with my existing sample Counter, and it returns the minimum values with duplicates.

Comment: Data should be ordered in descending order just as in the example shown in the question. This code should give the exact same result as you showed in the example result too.